# Mongo query for the below result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a scenario where I want to find all the documents where the same value exists for different transaction ID’s. If the value exists in two documents for the same transactionID’s then it should not print those documents.
Below are few sample documents.

```
Document 1:
{
"_id" : 1,
"trxId" : “abcd”,
“transactionID” : “1234”,
“Value” : “abcd1234hjgn”
}

Document 2:
{
"_id" : 2,
"trxId" : “efgh”,
“transactionID” : “5678”,
“Value” : “abcd”
}

Document 3:
{
"_id" : 1,
"trxId" : “ijkl”,
“transactionID” : “12345”,
“Value” : “abcd1234hjgn”
}

Document 4:
{
"_id" : 1,
"trxId" : “abcd”,
“transactionID” : “1234”,
“Value” : “abcd1234hjgn”
}
```

The query should print only document 1 and document 2 because “Value” : “abcd1234hjgn” exists for two different transactionID’s.
The result should be below. How do I accomplish this?

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"trxId" : “abcd”,
“transactionID” : “1234”,
“Value” : “abcd1234hjgn”
}

{
"_id" : 1,
"trxId" : “ijkl”,
“transactionID” : “12345”,
“Value” : “abcd1234hjgn”
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long winded way but it gets to the result.

```js
db.getCollection("stackoverflow").aggregate(

  // Pipeline
  [
    // Stage 1
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$Value',
        records: {
          $push: {
            trxId: '$trxId',
            transactionID: '$transactionID',
            Value: '$Value',
            _id: '$_id'
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
      $addFields: {
        duplicates: {
          $size: "$records"
        }
      }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
      $match: {
        duplicates: {
          $gt: 1
        }
      }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$records"
      }
    },

    // Stage 5
    {
      $project: {
        _id: '$records._id',
        transactionID: '$records.transactionID',
        Value: '$records.Value',
        trxld: '$records.trxId'
      }
    },

  ]

);
```